# python deleting a certain number of lines from a file given a keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a file which has following  lines in it. (Pay attention to the new lines)

```
blah blah blah

ID:name1:1bj409ju9
how are you

Im good 100
blah blah

ID:name2:987krjtu
not so good

too bad 900
blah blah

some words blah blah
```

As you notice the lines start with "ID" have a pattern. My attempt is to search for ID:name[x] and delete 5 lines (including the space). for an instance say i want to delete below set of lines from the file.

```
ID:name1:10.1.1.10
how are you

I'm good 100
blah blah
```

I tried the following code but it deletes only the lines matching "somename1"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput

filename = r"file.txt"
counter = -1
for linenum,line in enumerate(fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=1)):
    if "name1" in line:
        counter = linenum + 6
        if linenum == counter:
            line.strip()
    else:
        print line,
```

Please note that I want to get rid of the new empty line in between "blah blah" and "ID:somename2:987krjtu".

Comment: Could there ever be a variable number of lines? Technically don't you want to delete all lines until the next "ID:" line? In your code, you set a counter but don't really use it unless the line contains "name1". The high level if logic just checks for that string in the line and prints if it is not present. You need to do additional logic to use your counter value

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect `linenum == counter` when it's immediately after you made the count 6 greater than the line

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks. As mentioned I'm quite a beginner. Please correct the code with proper comments so that I will understand better. To be honest I came up with that code pretty much blindly.

Comment: how big is your file ? (just to know if you can load it in memory or if you have to stream it)

Comment: Not big at all. May be few  100 lines now but can grow up to 2000 tops. However I'd like to learn both methods sir if you will.

Comment: actually the answer I posted works for both. I edited it to explain it a bit further

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
def delete_lines(name, finput):
    for line in finput:
        if line.startswith('ID:') and line.contains(name):
            # iterate finput five times
            for i in range(5):
                next(finput) 
        else:
            # print the other lines
            print(line)
            # if you want to have the remaining lines in a variable you could also yield them
            yield(line)
```

then call the function:

```
lines = list(delete_lines('name1', fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=1)))
```

lines will contain all the lines that have not been deleted.

Note that the same method should also work with an opened file descriptor:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as finput:
    delete_lines('name1', finput)
```

or with a list of in-memory lines (if you don't care about loading the full file in memory):

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as finput:
    lines = finput.readlines()
delete_lines('name1', finput)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file can fit into memory, use a regex

If you want to delete between [two patterns](https://regex101.com/r/9zzLuO/4/):

```
import re
with open(fn) as f:
    result=re.sub(r'^ID:name1[\s\S]*(?=^ID:name2.*)','',f.read(),0,re.M)
    print result
```

Explanation of the pattern:

```
^ID:name1[\s\S]*(?=^ID:name2.*)
^                                   Start of line
    ^                               First pattern
           ^                        A space and not a space - 
                                      a way of saying anything including new lines
               ^.                   greedy -- all of them
                     ^              stop before the end pattern
```

If you want `n` number of line following the matched line (vs two anchors) you can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dEBFPK/2/):

```
with open(fn) as f:
    result=re.sub(r'^ID:name1.*\s(^.*$\s){1,5}','',f.read(),0,re.M)
    print result
```

Explantation of this pattern:

```
 ^ID:name1.*\s(^.*$\s){1,5}
    ^        ^                     start pattern line

                 ^                 1 to five lines following
```